# Block not showing in custom frontend controller

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers

Here is my custom frontend controller

```
namespace Namespace\Testing\Controller\Payment;

class Failure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfacc
     */    
    protected $_order;

    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_messageManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
      \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_order = $order;
        $this->_messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
    * Unset the quote and redirect to checkout success.
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'test1';
        $message = '2132132132123132123';
        $this->_messageManager->addError(__('This is a erroor message.'));
        $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Namespace\Tesing\Block\Failure');

        return $resultPage;


    }
}
```

block class

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Testing\Block;

class Failure extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{
    protected function _toHtml() {
        return "<b>Hello world from block!</b>";
    }
}
```

The block is not added (i didn't find something like appendbody for resultpage) in the controller page. anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please post your xml file which is calling your view file?

Comment: @Ranganathan is it possible to add a block without xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Namespace\Tesing\Block\Failure');
 echo $block->_toHtml();
```

I suggest you should use layout (.xml) file to achieve this. That is the right way to do.

Comment: $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Namespace\Tesing\Block\Failure');  return false

Comment: He is correct....Use this code in your view file directly instead of controller

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong function **getBlock**. *GetBlock is called a block if it exists. I guess that you want to create a block and return it content then use below code.*

```
    $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
    $layout->createBlock({YourBlockClass},'mycustom.block') ;
    $response = $layout->getBlock('mycustom.block')->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
    return;
```

**So, the code of execute() is  below:**

> ```
> public function execute()
> {
>
>     $message = '2132132132123132123';
>     $this->_messageManager->addError(__('This is a erroor message.')); // message is not render as single block is output
>     $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
>     $layout->createBlock(\Namespace\Tesing\Block\Failure::class,'mycustom.block') ;
>     $response = $layout->getBlock('mycustom.block')->toHtml();
>     $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
>     return;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You Want to display the block message on the controller so Follow Below Steps.

1) Create Controller

```
namespace Namespace\Testing\Controller\Payment;

class Failure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


    protected $_pageFactory;



    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
    * Unset the quote and redirect to checkout success.
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;


    }
}
```

> 2)Create Block -> All Condition and Functionality Write Into The Block. (Not in Controller)
>
> 3)Create The Xml File in `vendor > module_name > view > Frontend > Layout`

Name Of that Xml File is look like => `test_Payment_Failure.xml`

Here, test is route.xml file path name then payment is your controller and failure is your file.

Then in This Xml File Declare the Block and .phtml File

> 4) Create .Phtml file and get the data.